# Ionic 2 do not show slides when exercise is done

Tags: angular, object, typescript, ionic2, angular-ng-if

Here I have the outcome of the JSONOBJ:[image]

I have `ion-card` in my home.html with the method `navigate()` which looks like this:

```
    navigate(event, exercise, exercise2, exercise3, exercise4){    
      this.navCtrl.push(exerciseSlides, {
                clickedExercise: exercise,
                secondExercise: exercise2,
                thirdExercise: exercise3,
                fourthExercise: exercise4
      });
  }
```

and these are 2 of the cards:

```
 <ion-card *ngIf="oefening1" (click)="navigate($event, oefening1, oefening2, oefening3, oefening4)" class="{{ oefening1 }}" margin-vertical>
    <img src="assets/img/{{ oefening1 }}.jpg"/>
    <div *ngIf="exercise1IsDone || allExercisesDone" (click)="$event.stopPropagation()" class="overlay">
      <ion-icon name="checkmark-circle" class="checkmark"></ion-icon>
    </div>

    <ion-card-content>
      <ion-card-title>{{ oefening1 }}</ion-card-title>
      <p>Setjes: {{ set1 }}</p>
      <p>Herhalingen: {{ rep1 }}</p>
    </ion-card-content>
  </ion-card>

  <ion-card *ngIf="oefening2" (click)="navigate($event, oefening2, oefening1, oefening3, oefening4)" class="{{ oefening2 }}" margin-vertical>
    <img src="assets/img/{{ oefening2 }}.jpg"/>    
    <div *ngIf="exercise2IsDone || allExercisesDone" (click)="$event.stopPropagation()" class="overlay">
      <ion-icon name="checkmark-circle" class="checkmark"></ion-icon>
    </div>
    <ion-card-content>
      <ion-card-title>{{ oefening2 }}</ion-card-title>
      <p>Setjes: {{ set2 }}</p>
      <p>Herhalingen: {{ rep2 }}</p>
    </ion-card-content>
  </ion-card>
```

I have an exerciseSlides.html like this:

```
<ion-content>
  <ion-slides #exercisesSlider>
        <ion-slide *ngFor="let ex of allExercises; let i = index" id="{{ ex.exercise }}">
            <ion-grid>
                <ion-row>
                    <ion-col col-12>
                        <div (click)="playVid(ex.exercise)" padding-bottom>
                            <img [src]="ex.path" />
                        </div>
                        <div text-center>
                            <!-- can't go back if it's the first exercise -->
                            <button *ngIf="i > 0" ion-button round (click)="previousExercise()">Vorige</button>
                            <!--<button ion-button block [disabled]="!disabledBtn">Block Button</button>-->
                            <!-- will not have a next exercise if it's the last one -->
                            <button *ngIf="i < 4" ion-button round (click)="nextExercise(i, ex.exercise, ex.done)">Voltooi</button>

                            {{ ex.done }}
                        </div>
                    </ion-col>
                </ion-row>
            </ion-grid>
        </ion-slide>
    </ion-slides>
</ion-content>
```

And an exerciseSlides.ts like this:

```
export class exerciseSlides {
  @ViewChild('exercisesSlider') slides: Slides;
  public fullPath: string;
  public disabledBtn: boolean;
  public allExercises: any[] = []; // INITIALIZE A VAR THAT'LL HOLD ALL EXERCISES
  public date: any = moment().format('L');

   constructor( public navCtrl: NavController, private streamingMedia: StreamingMedia, public params: NavParams, public modalCtrl: ModalController) {
        // GET ALL EXERCISES AND THE IMAGE PATH ON PAGE CONSTRUCRION
        this.allExercises.push({
            exercise: params.get("clickedExercise"),
            path: 'assets/img/' + params.get("clickedExercise") + '.jpg',
            done: false
        });
        this.allExercises.push({
            exercise: params.get("secondExercise"),
            path: 'assets/img/' + params.get("secondExercise") + '.jpg',
            done: false
        });
        this.allExercises.push({
            exercise: params.get("thirdExercise"),
            path: 'assets/img/' + params.get("thirdExercise") + '.jpg',
            done: null
        });
        this.allExercises.push({
            exercise: params.get("fourthExercise"),
            path: 'assets/img/' + params.get("fourthExercise") + '.jpg',
            done: null 
        });     

        this.disabledBtn = false;
    }

    ionViewDidEnter() {
        // block the swipe to change page
        this.slides.lockSwipes(true);     
    }

    nextExercise(i, id, done) {
        this.slides.lockSwipes(false);
        this.slides.slideNext();
        this.slides.lockSwipes(true);

        //Here is set the done value of opened slide to true, but gets overrided by the constructor.
        this.allExercises[i].done = true;

        console.log(this.allExercises[i].done);

        if (this.allExercises[i].exercise == 'lagerugklacht'){
            console.log('check', this.allExercises[i]);
            localForage.setItem('exercise1IsDone', [this.allExercises[i].exercise, this.allExercises[i].done]);    
            console.log('localForageItem: ', localForage.getItem("exercise1IsDone"));
        }

        let modal = this.modalCtrl.create(ModalPage);
        modal.present();

        if(i == 3){
            console.log("lastOne");
            this.navCtrl.push(HomePage);
            localForage.setItem('didAllExercises', [true, this.date]);
        }
    }
}
```

How do I set the value of `this.allExercises[i].done` to true and create an `*ngIf` to check if exercise is done, and when its done than do not show slide anymore?

The `allExercises.done` will always enters first to false because I set that in the constructor it changes after I emit the `nextExercise()` but how can I change the poperty of `allExercises.done` to true in the array and stays true? So if its done it has to skip that slide and move on to the next one which is not done.

Comment: Can you post the structure of a exercise? is it a object? Does it come from a server? How do you get your exercises?

Comment: It is an json object from an mysql server. Which looks like this:

`{"OEFENING1": 'lagerugklacht',"OEFENING2":'nekklacht',"OEFENING3":null,"OEFENING4":null,"GOALS":null}`

Comment: @GabrielBarreto I added a picture of my console.log

Answer (score 0):

So here's what you can do:

You'll need to update your database so every exercise have a `done` field.

I don't know how much exercises do you have, but select only 4 where `done: false`.

It's really good to have offline data that your user can see at anytime, but since this is a app that fetchs videos i think there's no need for keeping a localForage/localStorage for this, only if you have a page where the user can see what exercises he has done.

Don't save arrays, it's bad, it's ugly, it's not so good for you to manipulate. Use objects

So on your `nextExercise` you can do this

```
nextExercise(i, id, done) {
  // SAVE YOUR EXERCISE FOR THIS USER ON YOUR DATABASE, YOU HAVE THE EXERCISE ID
  // IT'S SO MUCH EASIER FOR YOU TO KEEP TRACK.
  // AND IF THE USER DELETES THE APP AND INSTALL AGAIN, YOU CAN DOWNLOAD HIS PROGRESS
  saveYourExerciseMethod().then(() =>{
    this.slides.lockSwipes(false);
    this.slides.slideNext();
    this.slides.lockSwipes(true);

    // I DON'T KNOW HOW LOCALFORAGE WORKS, BUT IF YOU HAVE A STATIC 'exercise1IsDone'
    // THEM IT'LL ALWAYS OVERRIDE THAT EXERCISE, YOU'LL NEVER COMPLETE ANOTHER
    // EXERCISE
    // YOU'LL NEED TO SAVE AN OBJECT WITH ALL YOUR EXERCISES COMPLETED OR
    // SET THE NAME DINAMICALLY
     localForage.setItem(this.allExercises[i].exercise, { exercise: this.allExercises[i].exercise, done: true]);

    // DON'T KNOW WHAT THIS DO, SO I1LL NOT CHANGE IT
    let modal = this.modalCtrl.create(ModalPage);
    modal.present();

    if(i == 3){
        this.navCtrl.push(HomePage);
        localForage.setItem('didAllExercises', {completed: true, date: this.date});
    }
  });
}
```

So as far as i understod your code and application, this is what i can adivise you. Can't post more code because this is what i can do for what i've seen.

Hope this helps you

Comment: I use that localStorage of each exercise because I am checking if the user has done the exercise and show the overlay on the cards with a checkmark. And I tried to set an array item with all done exercises but it keeps overriding the stored array and will not added to the existing data. So basically when the exercise is done it has to store true what will show an overlay and it will not show up in the slider anymore because its done.

Comment: And if I get this from the db the value has to return false when the day is over. Is there no simple way of setting it to true in the exerciseSlider component? So I can check if it is true and than dont show up and skip to the next  slider which has`done: false`?